# Convert Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple drop down menu on a form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <select name="ddlSelect" id="ddlSelect">
  <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="-1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I would like to convert the values for each option to display in an email using a java script function but am not sure how to do this. Can anyone help?
Ex. -1 = Yes, 0 = No

Comment: Since JavaScript can't send email, what language are you going to use to process the form and send email?

Comment: Is this form in the email? or is the contents of the form submitted somewhere as an email?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Change the string `"-1"` to the number `-1` (as per the two answers so far)? If so, what does that have to do with emailing?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to a number in javascript several ways:

```
num = parseInt(elem.value, 10)
num = +elem.value;
num = parseFloat(elem.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
num = elem.value * 1;
```